# External Application receiving multiple Success Pings

Tags: callout, httprequest, asynchronous

For the SFDC Integration I send out a call to an external application and receive a Success status in my debug log(I am logged in as myself).  External application says they are getting multiple pings of “success” over and over for several minutes(5mins+).

FYI: SFDC sends SFDC Id to External Application and the External Application connects to SFDC using Integration user credentials and the WSDL to extract data.

To stop the multiple pings, I freeze the Integration user.  In my apex code I have a try catch for when I send my http request, and have set a request timeout(120000) in case there is a timeout.  When I go to Setup->Apex Jobs.  I can see that the Integration user has a status of processing over and over. I have also noticed in my Debug log there are times when I see two separate callouts sending the same data to the same endpoint.

```
public class ProcessHandlerShowAccounts 
{
    public static boolean isAlreadyRun=false;
    public class AccountParameter
    {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public Id accountId;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String name;
    }

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void handleNewAccounts(AccountParameter [] accountParameters) 
    {
         if(isAlreadyRun)
        return;
webServiceCallOut(accountParameters[0].accountId,accountParameters[0].name);
          isAlreadyRun=true;
   }  
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void webServiceCallOut(ID n, String a){

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        req.setEndpoint('https://something/Accounts'+'?sfdcid='+n+'&operation='+a);

        String username = 'hello';
        String password ='123';
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);

        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        //Create a new Http object to send the request object
        //a response object is generated as a result

        try{
              res = http.send(req);

        }catch(System.CalloutException e){
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }  
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the criteria in the process builder:
Account: 
AND (OR(ISCHANGED( [Account].Name ),ISCHANGED([Account].BillingCity ),
ISCHANGED([Account].BillingState  ),ISCHANGED([Account].BillingStreet  )
,ISCHANGED( [Account].BillingCountry ),ISCHANGED([Account].BillingPostalCode  )
,ISCHANGED([Account].Site_Use_Code__c  ),ISCHANGED([Account].Shipping_County__c  )
,ISCHANGED([Account].Phone),ISCHANGED([Account].Type  )
,ISCHANGED([Account].Industry  ),ISCHANGED([Account].DUNS_Number__c  )
,ISCHANGED([Account].Taxpayer_Identification_Number__c  ),ISCHANGED([Account].ES_Company_Code__c  ),ISCHANGED([Account].Customer_Class__c  ),ISCHANGED([Account].HQ_Internal_Customer__c  ) ) ,
 NOT(ISNULL([Account].Oracle_ERP_Account__c  )),  INCLUDES([Account].Business__c , 'something') )

Contact:
AND (OR(ISCHANGED([Contact].FirstName ), ISNEW(),  ISCHANGED([Contact].LastName),
ISCHANGED([Contact].Department ),ISCHANGED([Contact].LastModifiedDate )
,ISCHANGED([Contact].Title ),ISCHANGED([Contact].Phone ),ISCHANGED([Contact].Email ),ISCHANGED([Contact].OwnerId ) ) ,
 NOT(ISNULL([Contact].Account.Oracle_ERP_Account__c )),  INCLUDES([Contact].Account.Business__c, 'something') )

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have issues with your Apex code. Its more like process builder is getting called again via field update and its again triggering .

Whenever you are calling your invocable method can you add this check in your process builder block. This will make sure you don't call the same block again and again.

[image]

If you want to fix it using the code, you have to use a static variable to store the state. Then check the state before making a callout.

```
public class ProcessHandlerShowAccounts {
    public static boolean isAlreadyRun=false;
     @InvocableMethod
    public static void handleNewAccounts(AccountParameter [] accountParameters) 
    {
        if(isAlreadyRun)
        return;

        webServiceCallOut(accountParameters[0].accountId,accountParameters[0].name);
        isAlreadyRun = true;
    }  
}
```

Comment: What the pros of using the apex code vs the checkbox in the process builder?

Comment: Someone can add another process builder that can call same invocable method, so you have to make sure each process builder is proper. Having it in code will make sure no whatever process builder, wf etc is written your method will only get executed once.

Comment: Thank you, but What will happen when you return before the webServiceCallout?

Comment: It won't do a callout...

Comment: Yeah it did not work, I updated my code and added a image to reflect what is going on in apex jobs

Comment: How are you loading data? Is it via UI?

Comment: Yes, I am the user on the bottom of the image(I crossed out)  The External application uses the Integration user credentials along with the WSDL and pulls data using a query.

Comment: As I can see.. there is only one future call from your user.... Which was the requirement.. mutiple future calls are because your external user is also updating the same record, which in turns upates the same workflow and the chain goes on and on.... Its like infinite loop...

Comment: Why would the external user update the same record?  Is there anything I can do to prevent them from calling the future method? Maybe triger the process builder for users !=Integration user?

Comment: Why can't he? You are providing him recordID in your callout, he definitely can... and is..  Can you edit and post the proceess builder screenshot as welll, if there is anything obvious it would be pointed out

Comment: Sure, do you want to see the criteria for each condition?

Comment: Would love to have precise data, show for a condition or fileds changes which calls the invocablemethod.

Comment: Sure, I posted the process builder.